# MAMP Pro (5.5.1) and officially signed SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, mamp

I'm trying to get an offiically signed SSL certificate to work under MAMP Pro 5.5.1 running OS X Catelina.

I created the .key and .csr file via the command line (like I've done for ages with Apache and OS X Server) like this:

sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out certificate.key 2048

sudo openssl req -new -key certificate.key -out certificate.csr

The CSR I uploaded to my SSL provider (Xolphin), after getting back the certificate file, I put these in the /Applications/MAMP/Library/OpenSSL/certs directory, and select them from within the MAMP Pro app under the SSL tab. After doing this, MAMP restarts, but then comes back with an error message that Apache can't be started.

This is what the Apache SSL Error log file mentions:

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] Init: Unable to read pass phrase [Hint: key introduced or changed before restart?]

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Sat Dec 28 19:49:47 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] Init: Private key not found

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218640442 error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 67710980 error:04093004:rsa routines:OLD_RSA_PRIV_DECODE:RSA lib

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218529960 error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:26 2019] [error] SSL Library Error: 218595386 error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error

[Sat Dec 28 19:51:30 2019] [error] Init: Private key not found

MAMP support desk tells me: "we can only consult you on the (self signed) SSL certificates created inside the MAMP application" but that's not what I want obvoiusly for professional (why I bought MAMP Pro) websites.

If someone got this to work, can you please tell me how you created the SSL certificate?

Cheers!

Léon.

Answer (score 0):

Topic can be closed. Solved the problem by creating SSL crs and key file in the following way:

openssl genrsa -out certificate.key 2048

openssl req -out certificate.csr -keycertificate.key -new -sha256

Hope this helps someone in the future who's running into the same problems.